# Vue - Eslint Complaining About Missing Variable in Setup Script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, eslint, vue-script-setup

Funnily the Vue js documentation is highly suggesting to use the `<script setup>` syntax of the Composition API, the problem with it is that the documentation is very basic and it interferes with other tools (like eslint).
I have this component:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h3>User List</h3>
   <highup-table
     data="{{users}}"
     fields="{{tableFields}}"
   />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {HTTPClient} from "@/services/HTTPClient"
import HighupTable from '@/components/table/HighupTable'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const users = ref([])
const tableFields = {
  email: 'Email',
  first_name: 'First Name',
  last_name: 'Last Name',
  username: 'Username'
}

users.value = await HTTPClient.getData('/user-manager/users').then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  return data.data;
})

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The issue I'm facing is that eslint keeps complaining that the tableFields variable is not used, although it's used as a prop value in the template.
I read in some articles that some eslint configuration might help with this, but I'm not very familiar with it, my project directory doesn't even have an `.eslingrc.js` file.
Wondering if it's worth playing with it, or is it better to just simply disabling eslint.
Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Your files wouldn't be going through validation if a configuration didn't exist.  [Several different config files](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) are possible, including configuration directly inside of `package.json`.  You're sure you have no eslint config at all?

Comment: Hi Yoduh, it seems that package.json contains some eslint configuratoin. I need to look into the documentation in more depth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your usage.

Correct usage: `<highup-table :data="users" :fields="tableFields" />`
or `<highup-table v-bind:data="users" v-bind:fields="tableFields" />`

You can learn more information here: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind

Comment: That was right, I did try to bind them before, but at that time I forgot to remove the curly brackets. Quite silly mistake. Thank you.